# Permission denied (publickey) error

Tags: windows-7, ssh, git, github

I'm trying to connct to github via shh with using following command:

```
ssh -v github.com
```

But i have error Permission denied (publickey).
I generated rsa keys with ssh-keygen command keys are located by the following pathes:

```
c:\Users\username\.ssh\id_rsa
c:\Users\username\.ssh\id_rsa.pub
```

I checked public keys (local and on github), i'm sure thay are the same.
Here is debug info:

```
OpenSSH_4.6p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8e 23 Feb 2007
debug1: Reading configuration data /c/Users/username/.ssh/config
debug1: Connecting to github.com [207.97.227.239] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /c/Users/username/.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/username/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/username/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.1p1 Debian-5github2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.1p1 Debian-5github2 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_4.6
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /c/Users/username/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/username/.ssh/identity
debug1: Offering public key: /c/Users/username/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/username/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Can someone give me ad advice how to fix this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check that the public key is **exactly** the same (no spaces or newlines) on github as the public key you have locally. Are you able to log in with ssh directly (using putty for example)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's my mistake. I had to run following command:

```
ssh -v git@github.com
```

Answer (score 1):

*SSH* will refuse to use any key file that is not readable only by the owner. Make sure that the *private* and *public* keys are readable only by you (`chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa.*`)

Comment: ohh its on windows. *blush* perhaps it has something similar.